# Materialize select muliple "Check/Uncheck All" event

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, multi-select

I have following markup

```
<select ng-model="sltStatus" id="sltStatusFilter" multiple class="right">
    <option value="0">View All</option>
    <option value="1">Study 1</option>
    <option value="2">Study 2</option>
    <option value="3">Study 3</option>
    <option value="4">Study 4</option>
</select>
```

And below is the JavaScript code

```
$('select').material_select();
```

Materialize use checkboxes for this.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xv0p06d3/16/)

How can I have check/uncheck all functionality, I Googled a lot but din't find anything related.

Comment: so you want to check / uncheck all the options inside the select when option with value 0 is clicked or? Could you explain it a little more?

Comment: Where is your checkbox ?

Comment: @mnemosdev, you are rigth, but those select options are overlapped by checknboxes

Comment: @DavidJorHpan, materialize overlaps options with checkboxes

Comment: would you mind creating a pen or jsbin for this?

Comment: How would you like the "select all/ deselect all" to look? a button?

Comment: @ThomasMoors as in fiddle the first item in list should check / uncheck the rest items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand from your comments, I think that this is what you want

```
$('ul.dropdown-content li').first().click(function(){    
  $('ul.dropdown-content li:not(:first-child)').each(function(index) {
           $(this).find("input[type=checkbox]").prop("checked", $('ul.dropdown-content li').first().find("input[type=checkbox]").prop("checked"));                       
        });
});
```

updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/xv0p06d3/21/

just be carefull with this because I'm using what it seems to be a class from Materialize...so, if the class change, you'll need to change the code. You can find a way to use you own code to get the `ul`/`li` elements.

Hope it helps.

**UPDATE**
the answer above is pure jquery (as your fiddle as just jquery)...one way for you to make this work with angular is create a directive like this.

```
app.directive('selectMultiple', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            $(element).find('select').material_select();
            $(element).find("ul li").first().click(function(){  
            $(element).find("ul li:not(:first-child)").each(function(index) {
                   $(this).find("input[type=checkbox]").prop("checked", $(element).find("ul li").first().find("input[type=checkbox]").prop("checked"));                      
                 });
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Check Angular fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/TH87t/1545/

Kind regards.

Comment: Far more elegant than my approach but, as you say, the css selector must be chosen carefully)

Comment: thanks! yeah...he can just set an `ID` to the select and then use it to get the `ul`/`li` I'll leave this up to him. =)

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to mention that I need to implement it through angularJs, so I was guessing I am missing any inbuilt event of materialize multiselect

Comment: And I had tried this in controller, but this is not working

Comment: I had tried this way "$('ul.dropdown-content li:first-child').click(function(){"

Comment: @Md.ParvezAlam I've updated the answer...hope you manage to solve with this.

Comment: @ElmerDantas Thanks for your effort, but unfortunately its not working, its not calling,  I assume I need to ad selectMultiple in select tag

Comment: @Md.ParvezAlam updated answer and link with working fiddle. ;-)

Comment: What I am missing in this markup 
<div class="col-xs-6" select-multiple>
            <select id="sltStatusFilter"  multiple class="right" ng-model="selectedSttus" ng-options="item.Status for item in statusList track by item.Value"></select>
        </div>

Comment: @Md.ParvezAlam `ng-model="selectedSttus"` is not a typo for `ng-model="selectedStatus"` ? besides that, I won't be able to help without seeing the whole strucute you're working on. At least the select/deselect all should be solved, right?

Comment: I have copied and paste markup from fiddle but still its not calling directive

Comment: are you using the right name of app for the directive? the name I choose was TestApp and create a directive based on this. As I said..without your structure is really hard to help you. Your question is answered but how to you use the answer in your own project is another thing that requires more information ;-)

Comment: I wrapped up the code inside document ready and now it is working. Many Thanks for your support

Comment: Can I know what is restrict 'A'

Comment: @Md.ParvezAlam Glad that you manage to solve! `restrict A` means 'attributes'...so, your directive is triggered when you use it as attribute...in your case the `select-multiple` that you add to the `div` element. To understand better about `restrict` option...[See Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

Comment: @Md.ParvezAlam This doesn't work as expected. First, check few options, and then click on "Check All" option. It should check all other options but it doesn't. Same is case with "Uncheck All".

Comment: @Tushar, I have modified code a bit, and it is working as expected

Comment: What you need is to instead of simply firing click, set prop with check/uncheck

Comment: @Tushar I've updated the answer to fix the bug you've mentioned. (also update link to fiddle.)

Comment: @ElmerDantas, I know it should be new question but asking for a quick reference, I am using pagination on same page, found when DOM gets updated everything I written in directly lost, not working at all

Comment: @Md.ParvezAlam I don't understand what you mean...are you able to create a fiddle to show what you're talking about?

Comment: I mean when I update the some content of page, check/uncheck all no more working

Comment: @Md.ParvezAlam why do you mean by "update the some content of the page"...as I said, you need to provide more information or else it will be really dificult to understand...

Comment: @ElmerDantas , pagination just update DOM for the next page, or simply if when we update DOM, check/uncheck stops working, means whatever written in directive is no more working,

Comment: I think it needs to reinstate the directive written

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145101/discussion-between-elmer-dantas-and-md-parvez-alam).

Comment: @Elmer, is there any option to remove the 'Choose your option' text when select all?

Comment: @Kapur it is, just add `$(element).find("ul li").first().remove();` after the loop. But remember, if you need the select all option again you'll need to find a way to manage that

Comment: @Elmer thanks. It works. Facing another problem to validate at least one entry to be made for 'multiple' with validate js. Any idea?

Comment: @Kapur sorry but I didn't get what you mean...even so, here is not the place for this. Create another question or show your problem in another way...regards.

Answer (score 4):

MaterializeCSS does not support this feature internally. However, this can be implemented using jQuery's DOM manipulation methods.

1. Bind `click` event: The plugin will add `initialized` class on the `<select>` and a unique ID to the corresponding `<ul>` which starts with `select-options-`. We can use this knowledge to select the first `<li>` children i.e. "Check All" option from the dropdown.
2. Check if "Check All" is selected or not: The plugin will add the `active` class on the selected items. Using `hasClass()`, we can check if `active` class is added to the first option in the select.
3. Selecting/Deselecting other options: Using the previous step, we can get the status of "Check All". Using this, we can iterate over other options and trigger `click` event on appropriate elements.
4. **Bonus** Updating the options text: To update the option text, get the text using `text()` method and compare with `Check All`. Using `contents()` and `textContent` the text can be updated easily.

**Note:** This code completely depends on the DOM elements created by the third-party plugin. If after an update, the plugin changes the HTML structure this code will not work or need to update accordingly.

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/ed6p5sot/)

```js
$('select').material_select();

$('select[select-all].initialized').prev('ul[id^="select-options-"]').children('li:first').on('click', function() {
  var selector = 'li.active';
  if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
    selector = 'li:not(".active")';
  }

  $(this).siblings(selector).each(function() {
    $(this).click();
  });

  $('span', this).contents().last()[0].textContent = $(this).text().trim() === 'Check All' ? 'Uncheck All' : 'Check All';
  // Check values of selected options
  console.log($(this).parent().next().val());
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.96.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>


With "select-all" option
<div class="input-field col s5">
  <select multiple select-all searchable="search here..">
    <option value="0">Check All</option>
    <option value="1">Yellow</option>
    <option value="2">Green</option>
    <option value="3">Pink</option>
    <option value="4">Orange</option>
  </select>
  <label>Materialize Multiple Select</label>
</div>


<br />
Without "Select All" option
<div class="input-field col s5">
  <select multiple searchable="Animals">
    <option value="0">Cat</option>
    <option value="1">Dog</option>
    <option value="2">Horse</option>
    <option value="3">Pig</option>
    <option value="4">Lion</option>
  </select>
  <label>Materialize Multiple Select</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Materialize is opinionated about how UX elements should behave and interact visually.
for that i suggest you to add personal jQuery function to fix you want to do like this:

```
    // Listen for click on toggle checkbox
$('#select-all').click(function(event) {   
    if(this.checked) {
        // Iterate each checkbox
        $(':checkbox').each(function() {
            this.checked = true;                        
        });
    }
});

<input type="checkbox" name="select-all" id="select-all" />
```

Comment: My client UI requirement not allowing me to add extra checkbox for select all, you can see multiple option in materialize allow to render top item as check all, but didn't find functionality anywhere

Answer (score 0):

Materialize is hard for customizing ! As you will see in inspect element your select is writing in some different div with class `select-wrapper` So I do it with that class for check/uncheck function ...

```
$(".select-wrapper ul li:first").on("click",function(){    
    if($(this).hasClass("active")){
        $(this).parent().find("li").addClass("active selected");
        $(this).parent().find("input[type=checkbox]").prop("checked", true);
    } else {
        $(this).parent().find("li").removeClass("active selected");
        $(this).parent().find("input[type=checkbox]").prop("checked", false);
    }    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem I found is that if you try to set the values with `$('select').val(...)` checkboxes are not updated. You need to update them manually calling `$('select').material_select()` again:

```
$('select').material_select();
$('select').on('change',function () {
    var selected=$('select').val();
  if (selected.indexOf('0')===0) {
    $('select').val(['0','1','2','3','4']).material_select();
  }
})
```

This workaround marks all options, but closes the select, and it seems that triggering the open action does not work. The documentation about that in the Materialize web is poor about this, maybe there is no option to control the component programatically.

Here is an incomplete demo, but you can get the general idea:

https://jsfiddle.net/xv0p06d3/23/